# Copilot in navigations options throwing error - TypeError: cannot react property 'getCurrentStep' of undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux-react and trying to use copilot library to create a guide for my app but it is throwing me following error -

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentStep' of undefined

Below is my code:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ copilot }) => <View {...copilot}>
                                            <MaterialIcon name="add" size={30} color="white" style={{marginRight : 8}} onPress={() => {
                                            navigation.navigate("CreateSomething");
                                            }}/>
                                        </View>;

class Abc extends React.Component{
static navigationOptions =  ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
        const {params} = navigation.state || {};

        return {
            headerTitle : <HeaderTitle title="Something"/>,
            headerRight : (<View>
                            <CopilotStep text="Click this icon to" order={1} name="addIcon">
                                <CustomComponent />
                            </CopilotStep>
                        </View>)
        }
    };

componentDidMount(){
 this.props.start()
    }
}
const exportedConnect = connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(copilot({
    verticalOffset: 26,
    animated: true,
    overlay: "svg"
})(Abc));

Object.assign(exportedConnect, {
    navigationOptions: Abc.navigationOptions
});

export default exportedConnect;
```

Am I missing something in the above code? Why is it throwing the above error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the part where you use getCurrentStep?

Comment: @Auticcat There is not getCurrentStep in my code. The error points to the line where I have used <CopilotStep>, so I was thinking may be the error is due to copilot.